# Serve arbitrary binary data without a Content-Disposition header in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have some image data returned from an API I want to serve from a controller in my ASP.NET Core application. The API outputs the data as a byte array.

If the URL is directly navigated to, I want to have the data viewable directly in the browser rather than presented as a download via a `Content-Dispositon` header.

Edit to add: This is not a duplicate of the listed question because the other question is trying to return data from a Stream and the solution is to use `StreamContent`, but this is trying to return a byte array. Also, this question specifically asks about how to avoid sending a `Content-Disposition` header with `FileContent`, which was the main piece of information I was trying to share posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a `FileContentResult` (or use the `ControllerBase.File` method), but provide null for `fileDownloadName`, or just use an overload without the parameter. Despite the name, this can serve arbitrary data without it being a forced-download file. There will be no `Content-Disposition` header.

```
var data = await someApi.GetImageBytesAsync();
return File(data, "image/png");
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to serve arbitrary binary data without a Content-Disposition header in an ASP.NET Core application, you can do so by creating a custom action in your controller and returning a File Result with the desired binary data and content type. To omit the Content-Disposition header, you can simply not include it in your response.

Here How You Can Achieve It :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

namespace YourNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class BinaryDataController : Controller
    {
        // This action serves the binary data without Content-Disposition header.
        public IActionResult ServeBinaryData()
        {
            // Replace this with your binary data or load it from a file or database.
            byte[] binaryData = new byte[] { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64 };

            // Replace "application/octet-stream" with the appropriate content type for your data.
            // You can find a list of MIME types here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types
            var contentType = "application/octet-stream";

            // Return the binary data with the specified content type.
            return File(binaryData, contentType);
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to configure routing and make sure that your application can access this controller action using the appropriate URL route.